# Python re.match doesnt match the same regexp

Tags: python, regex

I'm facing a weird problem; I hope nobody asked this question before
I need to match two regexp containing "(" ")".

Here is the kind of tests I made to see why it's not working:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match("a","a")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7467218>

>>> re.match(re.escape("a"),re.escape("a"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7467410>

>>> re.escape("a(b)")
'a\\(b\\)'

>>> re.match(re.escape("a(b)"),re.escape("a(b)"))
```

=> No match

Can someone explain me why the regexp doesn't match itself ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Regexes *don't* generally match themselves. It's not "find this string"; regexes are a miniature declarative programming language.

Answer (score 6):

You've escaped special characters, so your regex will match the string `"a(b)"`, not the string 
 `'a\(b\)'` which is the result of `re.escape('a(b)')`.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is the pattern object, the second is the actual string you are matching against. You shouldn't escape the string itself. Remember, re.escape escapes special characters in regexp.

```
>>> help(re.match)
Help on function match in module re:

match(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found.

>>> re.match(re.escape('a(b)'), 'a(b)')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10119ad30>
```